# google maps is working on local host with api key but not on test server with api key

Tags: google-maps, iis, google-maps-api-3

I cannot figure out why my google maps api key works on my local host but not when i post it to a certain server. Does anyone else have this problem.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'pages','viewed', 'Find Hoya Provider Page']);</script>
 <script src="@Url.Content("https://www.google.com/jsapi? key=key")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

<

the map loads in IIS but not when i type it in the browser on a different test server. It is the exact same api key. Does anyone know why?

Comment: you have to register the domains through which call the Google API. You can register them in the Google account you have for API

Comment: why then does it work on my local host? the domain would be                dal-itdev-srvr2:1357                                                                                              That doesnt sound like a domain. it is not  open to the public at all

Comment: what's the error message you are getting ? P.S. Don't post your key to public from next time

Comment: js?v=3&callback=google.loader.callbacks.maps&sensor=true:37 Google Maps API error: MissingKeyMapError https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#missing-key-map-error_.kb @ js?v=3&callback=google.loader.callbacks.maps&sensor=true:37
util.js:210 Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#no-api-keys
util.js:210 Google Maps API warning: SensorNotRequired https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#sensor-not-required

Comment: on iis the (the one that works) I only get the                   Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/… util.js:210 Google Maps API warning: SensorNotRequired developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/

Comment: I am not sure what exactly is happening here but can you try removing the spaces in your url. url.content doesn't encode url's and your url does have a space and that might be the reason why it couldn't find your api key

Comment: Sounds like you aren't actually including the key for the map.  How are you including the Google Maps JavaScript API v3?

Comment: first i tried using this script call  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>            but since that doesn't do anything ( even with my actually api key substituted for the words your_api_key) it doesnt work at all. When I do it my way which is above it works locally at least.

Comment: this is the link to my actual api key, if you click it still doesn't work <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAnk_asNfEXejjrUHsRAc13lBgKl6GeLOc&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>